# Switching php version unsuccessful on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-7.2

I currently have installed and running php 7.2 in my Ubuntu 16.04 OS. But I also have php 5.6 installed. When I try to switch php version to 5.6 with the following commands:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.2
$ sudo a2enmod php5.6
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
$ php -v
```

It displays the following message:

```
PHP 5.6.40-14+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I do the following in a browser it says:
    echo phpinfo();
it still says:

```
PHP Version 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Can anyone help me switch php version from 7.2 to 5.6 & then from 5.6 to 7.2 successfully.

Comment: You've got 5.6 configured for CLI and you need to run `sudo a2enmod php5.6` to make it work for apache most likely.

Comment: I already did that to. Just forgot to mention it on the question. I've updated my question now.

Comment: `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled` which version do you see in that directory?

Comment: I see these two files php7.2.conf and php7.2.load

Comment: a2dismod should be removing them. Does `ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available/` show php5.6 as an option? If so, you could try manually removing the 7.2 files from mods-enabled and symlinking the 5.6 ones. Do you have libapache2-mod-php5.6 installed? Something seems off.